# installing lxml on 64 bit windows

Tags: lxml, python-3.5

So I'm trying to install lxml on my machine, and I can't seem to get it to work.

I've got Windows 8.1 64-bit and python 3.5

I've used both

```
pip install lxml
```

and

```
easy_install lxml
```

I keep getting this error message:

```
C:\Users\jgarber\Downloads>pip install readability-lxml --upgrade Requirement already up-to-date: readability-lxml in c:\python\lib\site-packages\ readability_lxml-0.6.2-py3.5.egg Requirement already up-to-date: chardet in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from rea dability-lxml) Collecting lxml (from readability-lxml)   Using cached lxml-3.6.4.tar.gz Requirement already up-to-date: cssselect in c:\python\lib\site-packages\csssele ct-1.0.0-py3.5.egg (from readability-lxml) Installing collected packages: lxml   Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\jgarber\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-bypbiu8j\ \lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().r eplace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\jgarber\AppD ata\Local\Temp\pip-j8svsde4-record\install-record.txt
--single-version-externall y-managed --compile:
    Building lxml version 3.6.4.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command, \r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed *
*

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isosc hematron
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includ es
    copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\include s
    copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\include s
    copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes

    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes

    copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\include s
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib .win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win 32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win 32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron
-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstra ct_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schema tron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_i nclude.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematro n-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schema tron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-sch ematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schema tron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\ xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_f or_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schemat ron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt 
-> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\src\lxml
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo  /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc\lxml\includes
-Ic:\python\include -Ic:\python\in clude "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\P rogram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program File s (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\
8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcsrc \lxml\lxml.etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.obj -w
    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
    lxml.etree.c
    src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include f ile: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
    Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14 .0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    creating Users
    creating Users\jgarber
    creating Users\jgarber\AppData
    creating Users\jgarber\AppData\Local
    creating Users\jgarber\AppData\Local\Temp
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo  /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Micro soft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\in clude\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shar ed" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files ( x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /TcC:\Users\jgarber\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlX PathInit_qrahzea.c /FoUsers\jgarber\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit_qrahzea.obj
    xmlXPathInit_qrahzea.c
    C:\Users\jgarber\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit_qrahzea.c(1): fatal error C 1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
    ****************************************************************************
*****
    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 insta lled?
    ****************************************************************************
*****
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\B IN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ---------------------------------------- Command "c:\python\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\U sers\\jgarber\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-bypbiu8j\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(co mpile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __ file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\jgarber\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-j8svs de4-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed
--compile" fai led with error code 1 in C:\Users\jgarber\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-bypbiu8j\ lxml\
```

I have also tried downloading the .whl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml and attempted to manually install the wheel but receive this error message:

```
C:\Users\jgarber\Downloads>pip install lxml-3.6.4-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
lxml-3.6.4-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

even with the `python -m pip install` statement.

At this point I'm not sure what I'm missing, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would try using the [unofficial binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) that the LXML site recommends. These binaries include libxml so you don't have to install it yourself (which is currently the problem).

Comment: @Aurora0001 I've already tried that and it tells me that the .whl is not a supported wheel on my platform.  I have it stated at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Did you try the 32-bit version? I think Python installs as 32-bit by default on Windows.

Comment: @Aurora0001  yup the 32-bit version worked.  I was pretty sure I had set this environment up with the 64-bit version of Python and all, but oh well.  Thanks!  that solved my problem!

Comment: Glad it helped. Would you like me to post this as an answer then?

Comment: @Aurora0001 Yeah go ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Python will install as 32-bit on Windows, *even on 64-bit systems*. Therefore, to match this, you must select the wheel for 32-bit systems.

You can verify that your Python interpreter is 32-bit, because the REPL will look like this when starting:

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

You should pick the `lxml-3.6.4-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl` package for Python 3.5 on Windows (unless you explicitly selected 64-bit when downloading Python) which should solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

They fixed this issue as of lxml version 4.2.5.

If you are still getting this issue, see if your requirements file specifies a specific version of lxml. If so, you should be able to fix the problem by updating the specified version to 4.2.5 or above.

Comment: Thanks!  when I set up new environments I'll keep this in mind!!