# Facing problem regarding installation of lxml in venv,

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, lxml, python-3.8

I am trying to setup evalai-cli using pip,
but i am facing problems during setup when i try to run

```
pip install evalai
```

---

Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?

---

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\amana\evalai-cli\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\amana\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iwb_ci9r\lxml\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\amana\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iwb_ci9r\lxml\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\amana\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tu5o2fvl\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\amana\evalai-cli\venv\include\site\python3.8\lxml'
         cwd: C:\Users\amana\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iwb_ci9r\lxml\

---

ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

---

I have installed lxml using `easy_install lxml` & www.lfd.uci.edu
but still the problem remains
I am on windows 10 64 bit running python 38

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

then you **download** the file `lxml-4.4.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`

then open the **Command** and navigate to the folder containing the file `lxml-4.4.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`

then run the **Command** `pip install lxml-4.4.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: I have installed lxml using easy_install lxml & www.lfd.uci.edu but still the problem remains I am on windows 10 64 bit running python 38

Comment: Try to download the 32bit ```lxml-4.4.2-cp38-cp38-win32.whl``` then install it. maybe the python you installed is 32bit. @AmanSa

Comment: Like me, I use Windows 10 64bit but install Python 3.8.0 32bit. @AmanSa

Comment: Earlier it was so, but now i have 64 bit

Comment: try visiting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40387835/11587161) might help